# Vue JS. Сохранение данных формы

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Работаю с Vue JS. Возник вопрос: как мне сохранить данные формы после ввода? Например, после авторизации браузер должен спрашивать "Сохранить данные для этого сайта?". И после повторного входа данные должны быть записаны в формах.

И, думаю, сохранять где-то пароль напрямую небезопасно.

В многостраничных приложениях вроде все автоматически. С SPA не знаю как.
Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Данный для  форм можете сохранить в localstorage, а пароли не храните вообще.

Comment: Какие данные вы хотите сохранить? Авторизационные? Или данные в какую-то базу данных? (Типа анкета, которую нужно на сервере в БД сохранить) В общем, вопрос неясен: ни что, ни куда.

Comment: Мне нужно сохранять именно авторизационные данные. Данные для форм (логин и пароль). Чтобы при в следующем входе в систему, форма была уже заполнена.

Answer (score 0):

для этого у тебя должна быть форма внутри тега form
и кнопке задаешь которая субмитит форму задаешь type="form"